# Повышение скорости обработки с использованием Threadpoolexecutor Python

Tags: python, многопоточность, multiprocessing

Имею следующий код:

```
def fill_global(file):
  gl = open(file, 'a') #итоговый файл
  for zipfile in zip_list: 
    zf = open(zipfile, 'r') #открываем по очереди зип-архив из списка 
    for file in files:
      ff = open(file, 'r') #берем каждый файл, заархивированный в зип
      data = ff.readline()[1] #читаем в каждой строчке элемент 
      gl.write(data) #записываем элемент в итоговый файл

global_lists = [file1, file2, file3,..., fileN]
for globalfile in global_list:
    fill_global(globalfile)
```

Вопрос: каким образом можно снизить время обработки задания? Нутром чую, что в сторону threadpoolexecutor и/или processpoolexecutor надо смотреть, но не понимаю как одну и ту же функцию запустить в потоке?
То есть, каким образом нагрузить систему так, чтобы заполнение каждого файла из глобального списка происходило параллельно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать функцию [map](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) из модуля [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html), работая через объект [Pool](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool).

Доступный пример:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
from urllib.request import urlopen

def go(url):
    print(url, urlopen(url))

urls = [
    'http://www.python.org',
    'http://www.python.org/about/',
    'http://www.python.org/doc/',
    'http://www.python.org/download/',
]

pool = ThreadPool()
pool.map(go, urls)
```

---

В синхронном варианте было бы:

```
...
for url in urls:
    go(url)
```

---

Если функция обработки возвращает результат и его нужно получить:

```
...
def go(url):
    rs = urlopen(url)
    print(url, rs)
    return rs


pool = ThreadPool()
result = pool.map(go, urls)
print(result)
```

---

PS. в `from multiprocessing.dummy`, dummy означает, что использоваться будут не процессы, а потоки